# Automated update if key exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
PARTSUPP - table

PS_PARTKEY
PS_SUPPKEY
PS_AVAILQTY
PS_SUPPLYCOST
PS_COMMENT
S_NAME
```

and

```
SUPPLIER - table

S_SUPPKEY
S_NAME
S_ADDRESS
S_NATIONKEY
S_PHONE
S_ACCTBAL
S_COMMENT
```

Then what i need:

1 - iterate updating PARTSUPP.S_NAME with SUPPLIER.S_NAME where PARTSUPP.PS_SUPPKEY = SUPPLIER.S_SUPPKEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unusual that you need to do something like this and might be an indication that your database design is flawed. Did you actually intentionally denormalize your model (and cache SUPPLIER.S_NAME in other table) for performance reasons? If not, consider changing the design (i.e. removing redundant PARTSUPP.S_NAME and using JOIN in run-time).

That being said, you can do the update you asked for like this:

```
UPDATE PARTSUPP
SET S_NAME = (
    SELECT S_NAME
    FROM SUPPLIER
    WHERE PARTSUPP.PS_SUPPKEY = SUPPLIER.S_SUPPKEY
)
```

Comment: Yes @branko-dimitrijevic is for performance reason. Now im migrating a relational database to monodb and without denormalize the relacional database it's spend much time. Denormalizing the table a need search one table only, and than get faster results.

Comment: @ulima69 Then may I suggest doing this update and indeed enforcing the equality from triggers? Alternatively, you may consider the normalized design, but with natural keys and InnoDB, which would physically sort the rows, making merge joins very efficient (or at least this is what I would expect from equivalent Oracle techniques, I'm not that experienced with MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

i think you want is `UPDATE PARTSUPP p SET S_NAME=(SELECT S_NAME FORM SUPPLIER s WHERE s.S_SUPPKEY=p.PS_SUPPKEY)`

still you sould (if posseble) delete the partsuppp.s_name colum and cvhang the querys needing it in `SELECT * FROM PARTSUPP LEFT JOIN SUPPLIER ON PS_SUPPKEY=S_SUPPKEY`
then you not need to update it *(also reed more about databace design)*

Answer (score 1):

Could also be done with joins instead of inner queries:

```
UPDATE FROM PARTSUPP ps
INNER JOIN SUPPLIER s ON s.S_SUPPKEY = ps.PS_SUPPKEY
SET ps.S_NAME = s.S_NAME
WHERE ps.S_NAME <> s.S_NAME
```